# Are there Feynman rules to calculate form factors in QED?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I just learned about Feynman rules to calculate scattering amplitudes in QED. I was looking into the anomalous magnetic moment and was wondering how I could 'translate' these Feynman diagrams to proper maths. Are there also Feynman rules for these kind of Feynman diagrams (not scattering)?

I have not taken a real QFT course yet so a derivation of these rules is not needed (if they exist).

Comment: Do you know how to derive the feynman rules in general?

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux no they were just given

Comment: @Audrique I suggest you read some documents on the ways to derive the Feynman rules with the Lagrangian density. For the anomalous magnetic moment you only need vertices and propagators, no external legs are needed

Comment: @Audrique - Why do you want to do such a complicated calculation without first learning something as basic as finding out the Feynman rules first. What will you gain by doing a calculation by hand that a computer could do without understanding where the calculation is coming from? Even if you could do the calculation, would that give you any insight? Would actually learn anything? Please take your time to slowly learn QFT properly first before attempting such a complicated calculation.

Comment: @PraharMitra That is of course the goal in the end but for this particular course I had to summarize (no real calculations) a recent paper which had some connection with our class. This has to be done within a limited timeframe... But you are right I am not sure if that would make me learn anything at all.

Comment: @Audrique - That's good! You should mention that in your question so we can cater our answers accordingly. It's for us to understand your background and needs so we can help properly.